# How to down Android software version i.e. from Kitkat to JellyBean Plus

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, android-versions, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

My friend has a problem in his Android Samsung Galaxy Grand 2.

He updated his phone. After the successful update to version 4.3, his device was unable to connect to WiFi network, and can't continue past set-up.

The network is disconnecting every 2-3 seconds automatically.

I have no way to downgrade to 4.2 (because without WiFi it takes long time to download updates)

Is there another way I can downgrade to 4.2?

> I had searched very much on Internet for this : I found :
>
> (1) Go to Service center and they will make downward update 4.2
>
> (2) This is manufacturer problem in software updates, so we need to
>   update to 4.4 using 3G or 4G connection SIM card, if the update is
>   not released then we only have to wait

Comment: Please elaborate the question. Describe your device as well as the exact problem you're facing. The X.1.2 isn't helping much.

Comment: I have updated my quezstion with device name and android version name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can't downgrade your device the "official" way, however you can do it manually:

**THIS WILL VOID YOUR WARRANTY!**

1. Go to [www.sammobile.com](http://www.sammobile.com)
2. Then go to firmwares.
3. Search the right firmware for your device.
4. Download Odin (do a google search)
5. Extract Odin.zip
6. Put the md5/tar in the PA/PDA slot
7. Click on start/begin/OK.
8. Wait a few minutes and your will reboot.

Comment: @Kushal did it work?

Comment: My friend went to Samsung service center and updated to KitKat 4.4.. so he did not rooted device.. Thank you for your help